# Issue with setNickname in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Node.js Version: 10.15.3

OS: Windows 10

Scope (install, code, runtime, meta, other?): code

I am trying to set a simple nick naming function for my Discord Bot, but when I type in "!setNickname @username" it gives me this error message:

```
(node:20440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions at item.request.gen.end (C:\Code\ACCBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15) at then (C:\Code\ACCBot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:20440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:20440) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my code: (prefix is !)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); //looks in node_modules folder for discord.js
const {prefix, token} = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!')
})

client.on('message', message => { 

    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}setNickname`)){

        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        member.setNickname('cool guy').then((member) => {
            message.channel.send(member.displayName + "is a cool guy")
        })
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates your bot is missing permissions. It needs Manage Nicknames and possibly a role higher than the member's highest role in order to perform administrative actions on the member.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help.